# How to edit/update a nested resource on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to set up the edit/update action for a simple Rails 4.1 to-do list application.
Specifically I want to be able to edit and update my resources "projects" that are associated and nested within the resources "users". Currently I am getting the following error.

When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

```
  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project]) -------> error is in this line
       format.html { redirect_to([@project.user, @project], :notice => 'project was    successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
```

Here is my code:
routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users

  resources :users do
    resources :projects
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @users=User.all
    end

    def new
        @user= User.new
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)

      @user.save
      redirect_to @user
    end

    def show
        @user=User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])

      if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    #edit is related to the route patch
    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.destroy

        redirect_to users_path
    end

    private
        def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
end
```

projects_controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @project = @user.projects.create(project_params)
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end

    def destroy
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @project = @user.projects.find(params[:id])
        @project.destroy
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @project = @user.projects.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        #1st argument of redirect_to is an array, in order to build the correct route to the nested resource project
        format.html { redirect_to([@project.user, @project], :notice => 'project was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @project.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @project = @user.projects.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
        def project_params
          params.require(:project).permit(:project_name, :description)
        end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
end
```

project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

For starter, you need to tell your parent model that he will save along with a nested child model (or more), like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
end
```

In Rails 4, here's how you'll whitelist or allow the params you want to pass:

```
#UsersController
def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit([:id, :name, :email, projects_attributes: [:name,
 :price] ]) #list all the attributes that you want to allow to be passed from the       view  to the model when in the controller
    end
```

Still in UsersController, you need to pass the modified params, or **user_params** instead of **params**.

```
def update
  @user = User.find(user_params[:id])

  if @user.update(user_params) #this will already save your nested project along with the user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Since projects are being saved along with user in UsersController, I mean, you don't need to save/update projects in ProjectsController removing it from User and then saving it back.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes should be:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :users do
    resources :projects
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Also don't forget to whitelist your new attributes!